# Django simple template tag with "if"

Tags: django, templates, custom-tags

I have one simple custom template tag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def show_language_choice_dropdown_menu():
    return SHOW_LANGUAGE_CHOICE_DROPDOWN_MENU
```

which gets boolean value from settings. If I simply put it in text there is no problems, right value appears, but if i try to check:

```
{% if show_language_choice_dropdown_menu %}
```

it doesn't work - every time is False. What's wrong?

Comment: have you included it as {% load awesome_tags_file %} in your html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if you could do this way. The `if` statement looks for variable `show_language_choice_dropdown_menu` and probably there is no such variable. Try using assignment tag instead:

```
@register.assignment_tag
def show_language_choice_dropdown_menu_tag():
  return SHOW_LANGUAGE_CHOICE_DROPDOWN_MENU
```

and then use it as following:

```
{% show_language_choice_dropdown_menu_tag as show_language_choice_dropdown_menu %}
{% if show_language_choice_dropdown_menu %}
```

For more information please refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags